# Grid based wumpus world.This was given to me as an assignment and I'm confused with whitespaces

Tags: c++

```
// Print the grid  
int rowCount = 0;
int j;
for(int i =0; i<2*numRow+1;++i) {

    if(i&1) {
        cout<<"| ";

        for ( j =0; j<numCol; ++j) {

            if(rowCount == userRow && j == userCol) {
                cout<<" * |";
            }

            else if(rowCount == wumpusRow && j == wumpusCol) {
                cout<<" W |";}

            else if(rowCount == pitRow && j == pitCol) {
                cout<<" o |";}

            else cout<<"  |";}

        cout<<endl;
        ++rowCount;

    } else {
        cout<<' ';
        for(j= 0;j<numCol; ++j) {
            cout<<"--- ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
// Terminate
return 0;
```

}
[image: output is given below]

I CAN'T figure out the correct whitespaces for the given code. I've tried all different ways of output but it's not working. Can anyone help me with this. (I could not write the whole code because It was not letting me submit it

Comment: For your horizontal separators, print out a space followed by three dashes per column. For each cell, print out a bar, a space, a fill character (either another space, a w, or an o), and a space. When you're done with a row, print out another bar.

Comment: Could you make it work with a smaller grid, say a 1x1, or a 2x2? This is a try a smaller problem strategy.